# Form input won't change from default, then post via ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I've having a very annoying issue.

Firstly I have a form with one input textbox for a URL to be entered, it has an example url in there to begin with, now when the form is submitted whatever is entered the default value="http://www.test.com/image.png" is posted. Instead of the content typed within it.

Here's the form: http://pastebin.com/RkyPRGMe

Here's my jquery submitting the post

```
            $('#upload_links_form').live("submit", function() {

                var ajax_form_data = {
                    upload_links: $('#upload_links').attr('value'),
                    ajax: '1'
                };

                console.log(ajax_form_data);

                $.ajax({
                    url:'http://domain.com/upload',
                    type: 'post',
                    data: ajax_form_data,
                    success: function(msg) {
                        alert(msg);
                    }
                });


              return false;
        });
```

Can anyone spot something I'm doing wrong at all?

Comment: What does the fiddler tells you? Is there any request sent if you try to monitor it?  Everything "looks good" in my point of view.

Comment: The submit function is triggered even when you reload the form, so you must replace the submit event.

Answer (score 0):

Try using :

```
$('#upload_links').val();
```

Instead of

```
$('#upload_links').attr('value');
```

Comment: Tried that before, same result unfortunately

Comment: what does `console.log(ajax_form_data);` print?

Comment: note that upload_links value was the default, not what i entered in the input textbox

Comment: ignore blah sorry, test.com/image.png was the default

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
.submit(function(){...})
```

instead

```
.live('submit', function(){...})
```

Comment: I had to use .live as the form opens in a modal (qtip2) element, submit() wouldn't work for some reason. With submit it would skip my js and post the form via html, no good :/

Comment: Do you mean the server side? If so here: http://pastebin.com/HJFx4YFe but I do already know it's working okay there

Comment: can you check in network tab in firebug(firefox) or developer tools (google chrome), what data goes to server?

Comment: net tab shows this post data "link_upload Upload
upload_links test" I entered "test" in the textbox

Comment: then something goes wrong in server side, add something like this after 4th line `var_dump($_POST['upload_links']);`

Comment: var_dump outputs nothing :/ and $url outputs the default value

Comment: at least you know that the problem was in server side :/

Comment: also here's my controller, which triggers the previous pastebin (thats in the model) http://pastebin.com/LX3jGJQu that's now ALL the server side code

Answer (score 0):

You have return false for the submit event, why would you want to do that?
I guess you are not using the right event.

Comment: To prevent the normal form submission, removing the return false make it skip the ".live" function.

Comment: Try replacing the variable in ajax function i.e, 'ajax_form_data' with name value pair for example {'urlname': 'testurl'}
So that way you will know what the problem is.

Comment: Tried that just now, the default value is being POST'd :/ not my input.

Comment: Did you try removing the onfocus function from the input field? as it is just an extra functionality